# How to use debounce with useQuery in React Query?

Tags: reactjs, axios, lodash, react-query

I am using React Query to fetch data from an API in a React app. I want to implement debounce for better performance, but I'm having trouble getting it to work with useQuery. When I try to wrap my API call in a debounced function, I get an error saying "query function must return a defined value".

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
    async function fetchProducts() {
        const response = await axios.get(`/api/products?category_id=${category_id}&${searchParams.toString()}&page=${page}`);
        return response.data;
    }

    const debouncedFetchProducts = React.useMemo(
        () => _.debounce(fetchProducts, 500),
        [fetchProducts]
    );

    // The following queries will execute in parallel
    const categoryQuery = useQuery({ queryKey: ['category'], queryFn: fetchCategory, keepPreviousData: true });
    const productsQuery = useQuery({ queryKey: ['products', category_id, sortPrice, minPrice, maxPrice, page, categoryFilters], queryFn: debouncedFetchProducts, keepPreviousData: true, staleTime: 1000 });
```

When I run this, I get an error saying "query function must return a defined value". I believe this is because the debounced function returns a promise, but useQuery expects an actual value.

I have also tried using useAsync, but I would like to use useQuery because it has built-in caching.

Can someone help me figure out how to implement debounce with useQuery in React Query?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can utilize the [useDebounce](https://usehooks.com/useDebounce/) hook to trigger a `queryKey` update in react-query instead of using the `debounce` function from the Underscore library.

For example:

```
const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useDebounce([category_id, sortPrice, minPrice, maxPrice, page, categoryFilters], 1000)
const productsQuery = useQuery({ queryKey: ['products', ...searchParams], queryFn: fetchProducts, keepPreviousData: true, staleTime: 1000 });
```

`useDebounce` is applied to the searchParams array, which includes variables like category_id, sortPrice, minPrice, maxPrice, page, and categoryFilters.

The debounce delay is set to 1000 milliseconds (1 second). The productsQuery then uses the debounced search parameters in its query key, ensuring that the `fetchProducts` function is only called when the debounced search parameters change.

You can find a working `useDebounce` example in this [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/ted8o)

Comment: I'm glad the solution worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the React build-in hook [useDeferredValue](https://react.dev/reference/react/useDeferredValue)

> Showing stale content while fresh content
> is loading
> Call useDeferredValue at the top level of your component to defer updating some part of your UI.

Comment: I'm not quite sure that useDefferedValue would help with react-query. See the note at the bottom of your link: "If the work you’re optimizing doesn’t happen during rendering, debouncing and throttling are still useful. For example, they can let you fire fewer network requests.". useDeferredValue is better suited to optimizing rendering, not reducing network requests.

Comment: React-query uses a built-in mechanism to cache data, so it will not re-fetch for the same API with the same params unless the data is stale.
For example, if you use a search input that requests data on every 'onChange' event, the application will re-render after every key, with different API request params.
That will cause a new API quest for every re-render even using react-query.
Using useDeferredValue will reduce the number of re-renders of our application

Comment: You misinterpreted the docs. Yes react-query caches result, but as you can see, react-query is still called after each keystroke with useDeferredValue: [see console in sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/usedeferred-react-query-pygrhr?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A2%2C43). useDeferredValue still re-renders in the background. The only diff is that it might not commit intermediate changes if the client overloaded.

Comment: "Note that there is still a network request per each keystroke. What’s being deferred here is displaying results (until they’re ready), not the network requests themselves." - react.dev