# How to debounce in fetch function in useQuery?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I have a function for fetching data for an API (here is a fake API). I want to use `useQuery` for handling loading, fetching, and more. But now I don't know how to use debounce in `useQuery` in a way that just fetch data with delay not the other state. Here is my code.

```js
  const fetchRows = async (
    page: number,
    rowsPerPage: number,
    searchQuery: string
  ): Promise<ResponseData> => {
    const url = `https://api.slingacademy.com/v1/sample-data/users?offset=${page}&limit=${rowsPerPage}&search=${searchQuery}&sort=${sortDirection}`;
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data: ResponseData = await response.json();
    return data;
  };
```

```js
  const {
    data: responseData,
    isLoading,
    isError,
    error,
    isFetching,
  } = useQuery<ResponseData, Error>(
    ["rows", page, rowsPerPage, searchQuery],
    () => fetchRows(page, rowsPerPage, searchQuery),
    {
      keepPreviousData: true,
      retry: 0,
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
      refetchOnMount: false,
    }
  );`
```

I want to use debounce the `fetchRows` function that is used in `useQuery`. I read a little about `useDebounce` but I am not sure about using it.

Comment: i am afraid you need to implement debounce by yourself - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76030996/how-to-use-debounce-with-usequery-in-react-query or use lodash debounce for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't need to debounce the fetch. The fetch is happening because some component is requesting a particular data set (by it's cache key). What you want to debounce is the query key changing. Typically this would be done by wrapping the useQuery call in a custom hook that will debounce the state in the query key you'd like to avoid changing too often (e.g. searchQuery).

So in your case you might have a

```js
// assumes some reasonable useDebounce implementation...

export function useSearchQuery(
  searchQuery, 
  { page, perPage } = defaultPagination, 
  debounce = 200
) {
  const debouncedSearchQuery = useDebounce(searchQuery, debounce);
  return useQuery(
    ["rows", page, perPage, debouncedSearchQuery],
    () => fetchRows(page, perPage, debouncedSearchQuery),
    {
      keepPreviousData: true,
      retry: 0,
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
      refetchOnMount: false,
    }
  );
}
```

That you would use in your components where you can specify the debounce for the query state as an argument.